# Are Android Fragments View or ViewGroup

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, view, android-viewgroup

As the question reads, Fragments in android are View or ViewGroup. Can anyone explain

Here is the onCreateView method of Fragment from [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

```
public static class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

> The `container` parameter passed to onCreateView() is the parent
>   ViewGroup (from the activity's layout) in which your fragment layout
>   will be inserted

And

> To draw a UI for your fragment, you must return a View from this
>   method that is the root of your fragment's layout.

Comment: It's not View or ViewGroup.It's a Object and one attributte of it is a ViewGroup.

Comment: ah fragments, the first major mindblock in developing, the method you have written returns a view thats used to be put on screen. Behind the scenes the Fragment class handles what the container parameter is, (don't quote me on it but i think it has to do with the FragmentTransaction.).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot define fragments as views or viewgroups.Fragments are more than that.The easiest way to visualize fragment is to think of them as chunks of an activity having own xml appearance,own behaviour with own life cycle callbacks.They always run on top of an activity allowing you to perform operations such as add,replace etc on them at run time.This way you can switch between your layouts effectively and efficiently.
To understand `onCreateView` method,consider the following explanation:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
         View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);
      return view;

    }
```

this returns a single View object, always a `ViewGroup`, with the set of View object that defines the Fragment's UI. The `Activity` calls this event handler when it is time for the Fragment to provide its UI for display.

Answer (score 1):

Neither. `Fragment` is a base class.

From https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

> A `Fragment` represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in
>   an Activity

`Fragment` contains a field:

```
// The View generated for this fragment.
View mView;
```

that is generated in `onCreateView` which has the implementation:

```
@Nullable
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return null;
}
```

So if you want a `Fragment` with a `View` then `@Override` that method. And then the `Fragment` can be shown to the user if you use the appropriate fragment transaction from an `Activity` or nested `Fragment`.

Answer (score 1):

fragment is a wrapper over a custom view thats tied to host activity lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are a kind of Activity that don't take full screen,it can just split the screen into many fragments,so it is well used for phone and tablet .

Comment: yes you are right about the usage of fragments.But I want to know that is they are View or ViewGroup

Answer (score 0):

i think is no,activity(fragment) control what the view shows,viewGroup extends view and implements ViewManger.Only Activity loads related Views can the phone show the layout.Activity is a Group,view can work normally in this container